# Marionette Layout: overwrite a view onclick

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a layout view that works perfectly. Inside one of the four child views there is a button to create an "event". When clicked I'd like the child view to be replaced by a separate add event view.

I am unsure whether the add event view would be fired in the main layout logic or within the child view.

index.js (layout parent view)

```
define([
  "marionette",
  'app/views/images/collection',
  'app/views/topPosts/collection',
  'app/views/clients/collection',
  'app/views/events/collection',
  "tpl!app/templates/index.html"
],
  function(Marionette, ImagesView, TopPostsView, ClientsView, EventsView, template) {
    "use strict";
    var AppLayout, layout;
    AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
      template: template(),
      regions: {
        collection1: '#images',
        collection2: '#topPosts',
        collection3: '#clients',
        collection4: '#events'
      },
      onRender: function() {
        this.collection1.show(new ImagesView())
        this.collection2.show(new TopPostsView())
        this.collection3.show(new ClientsView())
        this.collection4.show(new EventsView())
      }
    })
    return new AppLayout()
  })
```

event/collection.js (which I believe would fire the replacement view over itself)

```
define(["marionette", "text!app/templates/events/collection.html", "app/collections/events", "app/views/events/item", 'app/views/events/create'], function (Marionette, Template, Collection, Row, CreateEventView) {
  "use strict"
  return Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: Template,
    itemView: Row,
    itemViewContainer: "ul",
    events: {
      'click #createEvent': 'onClickCreateEvent'
    },
    onClickCreateEvent: function () {
      //render create form over the events collection
    },
    initialize: function () {
      this.collection = new Collection()
      return this.collection.fetch()
    }
  })
})
```

event/item.js (model view for the collection above)

```
define(["marionette", "text!app/templates/events/item.html"], function(Marionette, Template) {
  "use strict";
  return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: Template,
    tagName: "li"
  })
})
```

I tried putting this inside event/collection.js, but it just wiped out the item views

```
onClickCreateEvent: function () {
      this.$el = new CreateEventView().$el
      this.$el.render(); return this;
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event will be fired in the view that contains the element that is clicked. However, the event will propagate up to the parent view as long as you don't call `stopPropagation()` on the event. The CompositeView should not be in charge of replacing itself, though; that responsibility should be given to the parent view (`AppLayout` I believe). One way to handle the swapping of views is this:

```
// index.js
AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
  ...
  events: {
    'click #createEvent': 'onClickCreateEvent'
  },
  ...
  onClickCreateEvent: function(e) {
    this.collection4.show(new CreateEventsView());
  },
  ...
```

One disadvantage to this approach is that the DOM element you are binding the event to isn't directly related to that Layout's template.